# Как из словосочетаний образуется предложение?

Tags: грамматика, подчинительная-связь

Мы знаем,  что **словосочетания** образуются на основе подчинительной связи (согласование, управление, примыкание). Подлежащее и сказуемое  связаны особой, **двусторонней** связью.

Ну а  дальше?   Как из словосочетаний образуется предложение?

И **дополнительный вопрос** по поводу связи «примыкание».

**Примыкание** — вид подчинительной связи, при которой к главному слову присоединяется неизменяемое зависимое слово. Связь между главным и зависимым словом осуществляется только по смыслу (Грамота.ру).

Ну ладно, в словосочетании еще можно их "склеить" по смыслу.  Но когда это словосочетание входит в предложение, что будет с такой связью?

Спасибо, очень надеюсь на ваши ответы.

**Справочный грамматический материал:**

http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#011

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (для лучшего понимания вопроса)

1. Грамота.ру приводит такое **определение** предложения:

Предложение — это совокупность слов или слово, **грамматически** оформленная с точки зрения времени и реальности/ирреальности, интонационно завершенная и выражающая сообщение, вопрос или побуждение к действию.

2. С точки зрения **смысла**,  предложение **по-разному определяется** в различных источниках, нет вполне законченного мнения на этот счет. Кстати, время и реальность вроде бы уже не считаются основными признаками предложения, а здесь в определении названо **«грамматическое оформление»** по времени и реальности.
3. Но сейчас я не об этом  спрашиваю,  то есть не о смысле, а **о форме предложения.**  Если использовать термин Грамоты.ру, то речь идет о грамматическом оформлении предложения. Или такой **грамматической связи нет**?
4. Что касается **смысла**, то вряд ли он может служить **способом связи** словосочетаний, входящих в предложение .

Кстати, это касается **и определения связи «примыкания».**  Разве корректно такое  определение, в котором смысл связывает слова . А какое определение дали бы вы?

**P. S.** Вопрос не показался вам интересным, не правда ли? Кому нужны эти грамматические связи, особенно если их, скорее всего, нет. Но я никогда не задаю абстрактных вопросов – меня интересует преимущественно то, что непосредственно **связано с практическим правописанием.**

Предложение – это **качественно новый грамматический уровень**,  к нему нельзя перейти, просто поставив рядом слова или словосочетания.  Если мы не видим этой связи, то это не значит, что ее не существует.

Comment: Понравилась идея построения предложений не из словосочетаний, а из **синтагм**. Прочитал об этом [здесь](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/38304/39-Filatova.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: Спасибо, это всё верно, статью обязательно прочитаю. Правда, в фонетике основным понятием является фраза, а синтагма - это часть фразы, но, возможно, здесь просто разный  терминологический подход.

Answer (score 1):

**ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

**1. О статье  «Синтагма как единица порождения и восприятия речи»**

Актуальні проблеми слов’янської філології. – 2010. – Випуск XXІІІ. Филатова Е.В., кандидат филологических наук, Донецкий институт туристического бизнеса

«Касаясь проблемы **синтагмы**, приходится констатировать: кроме отдельных мыслей акад. Л.В. Щербы , в русской и украинской лингвистике **вообще нет работ**, объективно отражающих **синтагму как реальную единицу** формирования и восприятия речи…. Проблема синтагмы, несмотря на свою исключительную важность для теории и практики речи, для обучения письменному изложению мыслей,  **только начинает изучаться».**

В статье говорится о важности синтагмы **как языковой единицы речи.**  Автор считает, что реальная речь (устная или письменная) имеет синтагматическую основу, при этом ссылается на работу **Виноградова**, в которой он ставит проблему и рассуждает о том,  какая единица – слово, словосочетание, синтагма или предложение – выступает в качестве основного "речепорождающего" компонента.

В качестве примера приводится предложение, разделенное на синтагмы:
***Все они, / ещё совсем юные, / беззаботные, / со счастливыми лицами, / играя / (и) азартно размахивая руками, / пели какую-то весёлую песню.***

Автор считает синтагму простейшей коммуникативной единицей речи, а предложение представляет как составленный из синтагм структурно-смысловой блок с конкретным, ситуативным содержанием.

Действительно, мы видим, что осложненное простое предложение **делится на речевые отрезки**, причем это деление в основном совпадает **с постановкой запятых** (кроме  отсутствующей запятой перед союзом И). Но при изучении правописания нас интересует не порождение речи, а **анализ уже существующего предложения.**  Синтагма  в данной работе  считается синтаксической единицей, но она еще и **фонетическая** единица.

**2. О науке, которая называется фонетикой**

Наука эта представляется мне очень замкнутой – если можно так выразиться, **наукой в себе.**  **Общего практического** применения фонетических знаний очень мало –  они все даются в начальной школе, а потом больше  не обновляются. Даже **характеристику звуков** мы изучаем на самом примитивном уровне, а это было бы интересно и важно для понимания слабых позиций, в которых происходит изменение звуков.

Что можно, к примеру,  сказать **о фонологии**? Здесь я оцениваю ее влияние как **негативное**. Понятие фонемы  (за сто лет!) так и не было освоено для практического применения (это надо иметь хорошую фантазию, чтобы смысловой звук превратить **в звукоряд**, с которым непонятно что делать). И все попытки применить фонологию для школьного фонетического анализа только **ухудшают ситуацию** – они запутывают детское сознание, а не проясняют его.

И вот теперь – **синтагма**, которая  изучается студентами первого курса филологических факультетов. Там же  дается общее понятие **о сверхсегментных единицах** – это слог, фонетическое слово;  речевой такт, синтагма и фраза (сегментной единицей считается только звук).  Они образуют **фонетическую цепочку** и имеют определенное соответствие **в грамматике**: звук – морфема – слово – словосочетание – составное словосочетание.

Слово образуется из звуков **за счет ударения** – ударный звук является **объединяющим** центром. Аналогично строятся остальные фонетические структуры, каждая из них имеет **собственное объединяющее ударение**, то есть ударение тактовое, синтагматическое, фразовое.

Хотите узнать, что это такое? Увы,  у меня  не получилось это сделать.  Вообще говоря, **ударение бывает** тоновое (тоническое, музыкальное), силовое и количественное. Русское ударение в одном из источников назвали  силовым с количественным оттенком.

**А тоническое  ударение?** Как оказывается,  у нас его нет, хотя при изучении интонации (правда, как единого комплекса!) говорится о **понижении или повышении тона** на одном из слогов. Чем бы, казалось, не ударение для суперсегментной единицы? Но нет, все они имеют **«просто ударение».** Вот и **логическое** ударение – это тоже "просто ударение".

Нет для  суперединиц  и четкого **определения**, поэтому различить речевой такт, синтагму и фразу довольно сложно. Студентам этот материал дается как **обзорный** (даже курсовые  работы чаще посвящаются фонологическим школам), поэтому сведения о суперсегментных единицах моментально выветриваются из головы. А те, кто не изучал вузовскую филологию, о них вообще **никогда не слышали**.

**3. Как из словосочетаний образуется предложение**

Как было сказано выше, можно построить две цепочки, **грамматическую и фонетическую**, между которыми существует **соответствие**, хотя и неполное. Но вот мы подошли **к предложению.**

Может быть, это очень сложное  и разветвленное словосочетание, к котором объединена группа подлежащего с  группой сказуемого?  Нет, похоже, здесь **соответствие заканчивается** и образуется **качественно новая** фонетическая структура.

Поэтому предложение имеет **две формы**, грамматическую и фонетическую.  Логично представить, что оно составлено из отдельных суперсегментных единиц – **фраз**,  структура  которых задается **фразовым ударением** (как мы помним, именно ударение объединяет звуки, слоги и слова в более крупные единицы). Это очень неплохая **рабочая модель** для объяснения знаков препинания,  которые ставятся преимущественно **на границах фраз**, там же (по движению тона) делается и **выбор** нужного знака.

Но для такой модели главное – **это четкость определений**, а у нас даже вид ударения сложно определить.  А вот еще пример: простое предложение называют **одной фразой,**  в которой тон сначала повышается, а потом понижается. Ну какая же это  фонетическая **ЕДИНИЦА, с двумя-то** ударениями?!

**Вывод.**  А может быть, я ошибаюсь  и на самом деле все эти проблемы **давно решены** современными академиками-лингвистами. Вот бы с кем проконсультироваться или чьи книги по этой теме почитать. Где  только они окопались,  эти наши академики?

Comment: Что касается моего вопроса, то он не только о том, как найти академиков. Мне интересно, почему эти люди ничего не делают для образования, почему они занимаются только своей научной работой, а о практическом применении знаний для пользы общества им и дела нет. Если бы так же поступали, к примеру, выдающиеся ученые-физики, то мы до сих пор бы сидели в пещерах без света. Наука тогда доказывает свою истинную значимость, когда ее результаты подтверждаются практикой. Для меня это самый важный критерий. Спасибо вам за комментарий.

Comment: Мы же не знаем, в чём они видят пользу для общества. Какой процент населения в Дагестане или Ингушетии не владеет просто разговорным русским на бытовом уровне? В этих республиках самая высокая безработица, а люди не могут выехать в русскоговорящую Россию  на заработки. Если бы я имел надёжную информацию о перспективах демографической ситуации в стране, я мог бы судить о правильности будущих реформ. Может случиться и так, что придётся "бросить всё" и срочно создавать какой-то "бэйсик рашн", пока не поздно. А может правы Вы, а не они -- у меня просто нет всей информации, чтобы понять.

Comment: Я могла бы им подсказать. Пусть академики напишут такую редакцию Правил орфографии и пунктуации, чтобы  они быстро понимались, легко запоминались  и в головах сами собой укладывались. Чтобы школьники  учили не правила, а разные стили речи;  чтобы умели писать художественные тексты, говорить ярко, образно, убедительно.  Пусть наши небожители вспомнят о народе, почитают Интернет и поймут,  кто нуждается в их помощи. И  ситуацию с  «экспертизой правил» тоже  возьмут под контроль, пока не началась «реформация».